# How to move all events on an "On my iPhone" calendar to an iCloud-synced calendar?

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, calendar

I have been using Calendar on my iPhone for a good while now. Today, I decided to open the Calendar app on my Mac, but none of my events are there! Both computers are signed into the same iCloud account.

After a bit of poking around on my phone, I have found that I've saved all my events to a calendar called "Calendar" in the Calendar app, which is in the "On My iPhone" section in the list of calendars, as opposed to the "iCloud" section of the list. This explains why it is not syncing: it is a local calendar.

I'd like to have all the events on my Mac. Ideally there's a way to change an existing "on my iPhone" calendar to an "iCloud" calendar. If that isn't possible, then hopefully there's a way to copy all the events from one calendar to another. I think I'd be able to do this on my Mac, but since we're starting on the iPhone I'm not sure where this kind of option might be hidden.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a third-party iOS/iPadOS file managing software such as **iMazing**. This would allow you to access your iPhone calendars and export them into formats such as **.ics** or **.csv** file. You can find more info [here](https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-export-iphone-calendar-to-csv-or-ical).

Answer (score 0):

macOS (on your Mac) and iOS (on you iPhone) will synch calendar entries via iCloud; you don't need aftermarket software to accomplish this. Apple has a support page on this subject [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203521).

You report having both devices logged into the same iCloud account. To synch via iCloud, however, also requires that you have selected (in both devices) the particular service you want to synch. For you, that service is Calendar. I suspect you may not have both devices correctly set.

Apple's page has this info at Step #3, which says:

> Make sure that you're signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID on all your devices and check your settings.
>
> On your iPhone, tap Settings > [your name] > iCloud. Check your Apple ID and make sure that you turn on what you want to update (Contacts, Calendars, or Reminders).
>
> On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Apple ID, then click iCloud. If you’re using macOS Mojave or earlier, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click iCloud. Check your Apple ID and make sure that you select what you want to update (Contacts, Calendars, or Reminders).

"Selecting what you want to update" means turning the software switch "on" so the switch shows green. The switch is the onscreen slider next to "Calendar" in the iCloud list of applications on both devices.

Comment: This isn't the issue - I have iCloud sync working fine for other calendars, it's just this one that is an "on my iPhone" calendar that won't sync.

Comment: @fnsjdnfksjdb Ah! I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks, now I understand the issue. I don't know how this might be done within iOS. If there's a backup, either in iCloud or on your Mac, perhaps Calendar data can be extracted from one of those.